# Calculate sum connected to selection from multiple dropdown in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown, multipleselection

In google sheets I need to create a formula, that will calculate the sum based on the selection from the multiple selection drop down list.

Lets assume that we have sheets "names" and "values"
in Sheet "names" we have column A with multiple selection dropdown lists
A
a,b
a,b,c
a,c
b,c

On sheet "values" I have that a=1, b=2, c=10 ...
So in sheet "names" I need to create column B, that will automatically calculate the sum of selected in column A letters.

```
A.       B
a,b.    1+2=2
a,b,c.  1+2+10=13
a,c.    1+10=11
b,c.    2+10=12
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=arrayformula(SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A1,","),$D$1:$E$3,2,FALSE),0)))
```

And drag it down. This assumes that all values in `A` are separated by "," and no other characters and also assumes `0` if letter is not found.
Result:

[image]

Or

```
=byrow(A1:A6,lambda(z,arrayformula(SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(z,","),$D$1:$E$3,2,FALSE),0)))))
```

To spill result at once.

Comment: Something is not working for me, could it be because my columnt A is not in fact a list of values separated by coma, by a dropdown selection list? I just get 0 as a result

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Is it possible that there are spaces in values, i.e. "a, b" instead of "a,b" Also did you adapt range for VLOOKUP to search in other sheet? You add link to dummy file or add print screen - it would be easier to debug

Comment: Thank you ) Everything worked nicely, was a bit issue with a separator, but I was lucky to find it )

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with REGEXMATCH and FILTER, despite its delimiter:

```
=SUM(FILTER(values!B:B,INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A1,values!A:A)),values!A:A<>""))
```

Also as an array:

```
=BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(each,SUM(FILTER(values!B:B,INDEX(REGEXMATCH(each,values!A:A)),values!A:A<>""))))
```

Comment: Nice one! but it also assumes that no more than 1 symbol is used to determine value in value sheet. For example "ab" with a=1, b=2, ab=5 would return 8